# Custom sql export result in duplicate key error on import

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1062

I've created a database export of my database using my own php script.
To export the table structure I use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, to export the contents of my tables I select everything that's in the table and than create a query from it that looks like this: `INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (...), (..), etc.`
I save everything to a text file, first the create statements, than all the insert statements.

When I try to import the text file with phpMyAdmin I get an error:

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'name1012_parent_id'
```

This is the create statement of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `pages` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `templates_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  `status` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified_users_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '2015-12-18 06:09:00',
  `created_users_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `published` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sort` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name1012` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET ascii DEFAULT NULL,
  `status1012` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `name1013` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET ascii DEFAULT NULL,
  `status1013` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `name1027` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET ascii DEFAULT NULL,
  `status1027` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name_parent_id` (`name`,`parent_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name1012_parent_id` (`name1012`,`parent_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name1013_parent_id` (`name1013`,`parent_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name1027_parent_id` (`name1027`,`parent_id`),
  KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`),
  KEY `templates_id` (`templates_id`),
  KEY `modified` (`modified`),
  KEY `created` (`created`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `published` (`published`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1051 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And the insert queries:

```
INSERT INTO `pages` (`id`,`parent_id`,`templates_id`,`name`,`status`,`modified`,`modified_users_id`,`created`,`created_users_id`,`published`,`sort`,`name1012`,`status1012`,`name1013`,`status1013`,`name1027`,`status1027`) 
VALUES 
("1","0","1","en","9","2017-03-06 11:49:05","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","0","de","1","fi","1","nl","1"),
("2","1","2","processwire","1035","2017-02-28 14:26:06","40","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","6","","1","","1","","1"),
("3","2","2","page","21","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","0","","1","","1","","1"),
("6","3","2","add","21","2017-02-28 14:26:15","40","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","0","","1","","1","","1"),
("7","1","2","trash","1039","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","7","","1","","1","","1"),
("8","3","2","list","1045","2017-02-28 14:26:18","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","1","","1","","1","","1"),
("9","3","2","sort","1047","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","","1","","1","","1"),
("10","3","2","edit","1045","2017-02-28 14:26:18","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","3","","1","","1","","1"),
("11","22","2","template","21","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","0","","1","","1","","1"),
("16","22","2","field","21","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","","1","","1","","1"),
("21","2","2","module","21","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","","1","","1","","1"),
("22","2","2","setup","21","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","1","","1","","1","","1"),
("23","2","2","login","1035","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","4","","1","","1","","1"),
("27","1","29","http404","1035","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","3","2017-02-28 14:25:36","5","","1","","1","","1"),
("28","2","2","access","13","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","3","","1","","1","","1"),
("29","28","2","users","29","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","0","","1","","1","","1"),
("30","28","2","roles","29","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","1","","1","","1","","1"),
("31","28","2","permissions","29","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","","1","","1","","1"),
("32","31","5","page-edit","25","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","","1","","1","","1"),
("34","31","5","page-delete","25","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","3","","1","","1","","1"),
("35","31","5","page-move","25","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","4","","1","","1","","1"),
("36","31","5","page-view","25","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","0","","1","","1","","1"),
("37","30","4","guest","25","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","0","","1","","1","","1"),
("38","30","4","superuser","25","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","1","","1","","1","","1"),
("40","29","3","guest","25","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","1","","1","","1","","1"),
("41","29","3","admin","1","2017-02-28 14:26:06","40","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","0","","1","","1","","1"),
("50","31","5","page-sort","25","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","5","","1","","1","","1"),
("51","31","5","page-template","25","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","6","","1","","1","","1"),
("52","31","5","user-admin","25","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","10","","1","","1","","1"),
("53","31","5","profile-edit","1","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","13","","1","","1","","1"),
("54","31","5","page-lock","1","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","8","","1","","1","","1"),
("300","3","2","search","1045","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","5","","1","","1","","1"),
("301","3","2","trash","1047","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","5","","1","","1","","1"),
("302","3","2","link","1041","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","6","","1","","1","","1"),
("303","3","2","image","1041","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","7","","1","","1","","1"),
("304","2","2","profile","1025","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","5","","1","","1","","1"),
("1000","1","26","search","1025","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","suche","1","haku","1","","1"),
("1001","1","29","about","1","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","0","uber","1","tietoja","1","","1"),
("1002","1001","29","child-page-example-1","1","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","0","unterseite-seite-beispiel-1","1","alasivu-sivu-esimerkki-1","1","","1"),
("1004","1001","29","child-page-example-2","1","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","1","unterseite-beispiel-2","1","alasivu-esimerkki-2","1","","1"),
("1005","1","34","site-map","1","2017-03-06 11:49:05","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","2017-02-28 14:25:36","1","sitemap","1","sivukartta","1","","1"),
("1006","31","5","page-lister","1","2017-02-28 14:25:36","40","2017-02-28 14:25:36","40","2017-02-28 14:25:36","9","","1","","1","","1"),
("1007","3","2","lister","1","2017-02-28 14:25:36","40","2017-02-28 14:25:36","40","2017-02-28 14:25:36","8","","1","","1","","1"),
("1009","22","2","languages","16","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","","1","","1","","1"),
("1010","1009","43","default","16","2017-03-09 13:55:50","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","0","","1","","1","","1"),
("1011","22","2","language-translator","1040","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","3","","1","","1","","1"),
("1012","1009","43","de","1","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","1","","1","","1","","1"),
("1013","1009","43","fi","1","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","41","2017-02-28 14:25:36","2","","1","","1","","1"),
("1015","3","2","recent-pages","1","2017-02-28 14:26:05","40","2017-02-28 14:26:05","40","2017-02-28 14:26:05","9","","0","","0","","1"),
("1016","31","5","page-edit-recent","1","2017-02-28 14:26:05","40","2017-02-28 14:26:05","40","2017-02-28 14:26:05","10","","1","","1","","1"),
("1017","22","2","logs","1","2017-02-28 14:26:12","40","2017-02-28 14:26:12","40","2017-02-28 14:26:12","4","","0","","0","","1"),
("1018","31","5","logs-view","1","2017-02-28 14:26:12","40","2017-02-28 14:26:12","40","2017-02-28 14:26:12","11","","1","","1","","1"),
("1019","31","5","logs-edit","1","2017-02-28 14:26:12","40","2017-02-28 14:26:12","40","2017-02-28 14:26:12","12","","1","","1","","1"),
("1022","31","5","page-edit-front","1","2017-03-01 13:01:39","41","2017-03-01 13:01:39","41","2017-03-01 13:01:39","13","","1","","1","","1"),
("1027","1009","43","nl","1","2017-03-09 12:57:23","41","2017-03-02 15:52:40","41","2017-03-02 15:52:40","3","","1","","1","","1"),
("1028","3","2","clone","1024","2017-03-02 16:04:07","41","2017-03-02 16:04:07","41","2017-03-02 16:04:07","10","","0","","0","","0"),
("1029","31","5","page-clone","1","2017-03-02 16:04:07","41","2017-03-02 16:04:07","41","2017-03-02 16:04:07","14","","1","","1","","1"),
("1030","31","5","page-clone-tree","1","2017-03-02 16:04:07","41","2017-03-02 16:04:07","41","2017-03-02 16:04:07","15","","1","","1","","1"),
("1046","22","2","jumplinks","1","2017-03-10 09:59:09","41","2017-03-10 09:59:09","41","2017-03-10 09:59:09","5","","0","","0","","0"),
("1047","31","5","jumplinks-admin","1","2017-03-10 09:59:09","41","2017-03-10 09:59:09","41","2017-03-10 09:59:09","16","","1","","1","","1"),
("1048","22","2","db-backups","1","2017-03-14 15:50:17","41","2017-03-14 15:50:17","41","2017-03-14 15:50:17","6","","0","","0","","0"),
("1049","31","5","db-backup","1","2017-03-14 15:50:17","41","2017-03-14 15:50:17","41","2017-03-14 15:50:17","17","","1","","1","","1"),
("1050","31","5","page-edit-protected","1","2017-05-18 10:42:59","41","2017-05-18 10:42:59","41","2017-05-18 10:42:59","18","","1","","1","","1");
```

Undoubtedly there's an insert statement with the same values. What I don't understand is why it is there. I fetch all rows from the original table and I put them in a text file. As I see it now, the original table should have duplicate entries as well but that shouldn't be possible because of the unique key.

The way I write it to a file is like this (simplified):

```
$tables = $this->getTables(); // returns a list of tables
$output = [
    'tables' => '',
    'inserts' => ''
];

foreach ($tables as => $table) {
    $output['tables'][] = $this->getCreateStatement(); // uses SHOW CREATE TABLE `tableName`
}

foreach ($tables as => $table) {
    foreach($this->getTableRows() as $row){
        $output['inserts'][] = "INSERT INTO `$table` ($this->fieldsToSql(array_keys($row))) VALUES($this->valuesToSql($row))"
    }
}

$fileContent = implode(';', $output['table']) . ' ' . implode(';', $output['inserts']);

file_put_contents('test.sql', $fileContent);
```

Again, this is NOT the actual code, this example above is a simplified version of my code. My code basically does the same thing.

The `valuesToSql()` method works like this:

```
$output = [];
foreach($arr as $val) {
    $output[] = '".$val."';
}

return implode(',', $output);
```

Comment: The big question is: how exactly your `valuesToSql()` method works. I would particularly be interested how it handles null values because my guess is your code translates null values into empty strings. I would check the`name1012` field of records with id 2 and 7 in particular in the original table.

Comment: @Shadow, I've updated my question to display the `valuesToSql()` method. It sounds pretty logical what you're saying, I'll look into that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `valuesToSql()` method translates `null` values into empty string. In MySQL the [unique indexes allow multiple `null` values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) being present in the index values:

> For all engines, a UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL. If you specify a prefix value for a column in a UNIQUE index, the column values must be unique within the prefix.

However, empty string is not the same as `null` and triggers the duplicate key error.

Furthermore, your code translates all values into strings, regardless what the real underlying value is. This may cause issues if the target MySQL server has `strict_all_tables` sql mode enabled, since a string is not a valid data for a numeric field.

To handle the `null` issue, I would check if the value is `null` and handle it differently:

```
output = [];
foreach($arr as $val) {
    if $val===NULL {
        $output[] = 'NULL';
    }
    else {
        $output[] = "'".$val."'";
    }
}

return implode(',', $output);
```

You can add further checks to the above loop based on the type of the data and modify the output accordingly.